# Ksoap simple array android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap

I'm trying to retrieve data from web service that returns an array of Strings .
I couldn't do it so I give you a snippet of code
 please help me I'm going crazy!

```
public void updateCategories(){
        SOAP_ACTION = "http://app.market_helper.com/getCategories";
        METHOD_NAME = "getCategories";
        Log.i("MESSAGE FROM me", "It's running wtf");
        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        Log.i("message to me",""+response.getPropertyCount());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I can retrieve data from primitive types but this is going a little bit complex .
this is the response from the web service

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<getCategoriesResponse xmlns="http://DefaultNamespace">
  <getCategoriesReturn>desktop computers</getCategoriesReturn> 
  <getCategoriesReturn>laptop computers</getCategoriesReturn> 
  <getCategoriesReturn>mobile phones</getCategoriesReturn> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <getCategoriesReturn xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </getCategoriesResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: if u get the solution post it here ..... check this link might be helpful for u .. http://ksoap.objectweb.org/project/faq/index.html ... according to them sending and receiving has to done via use of vectors ..but even i could implement it .. so pls pls share the solution if u have ..

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the string values with `response.getProperty(index).toString()` or if you want, `response.getPropertyAsString(index)` (index can also be replaced with the name of the property). To retrieve all string values, try putting them into a loop which adds the strings into a list.

```
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
int count = response.getPropertyCount();

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if(response.getProperty(i) != null)
        categories.add(response.getPropertyAsString(i));
}
```

I also make sure that the property is not null before adding it into the list.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Im not able to see the log message to be sure that Im recieving data
so what is the problem there the first log message is running I write it to be sure that the function is running but the second is not.
thank you for helping me and please tell me wtf?

Comment: What happens when you debug the function? Add `androidHttpTransport.debug = true;` after the line `HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);`. Then, in debug mode, you can after the `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` check for responseDump and requestDump inside your androidHttpTransport, to view the request and response in XML format.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

should be changed to:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

to use:

```
response.getProperty(Index);
```